# problem reading a publickey file and use the key to encrypt another file

Tags: java, encryption, public-key

I've been strugling with reading a publickey file which I want to get the key sting in the file and use it to encrypt another file. I'm using RSA PKCS1 v1.5 in encrypting and signing the file with SH1 hashing algorythim but thats not the problem, the problem is that I've been supplied with the publickey file to use when encrypting and I cant seem to win with reading the file and generating a publicKey object.

Here's the code:

```
void setPublicKey(String file) 
{ 
     try 
     { 
       FileInputStream keyfis = new FileInputStream(file); 
       byte[] encKey = new byte[keyfis.available()]; keyfis.read(encKey);
       keyfis.close();
       X509EncodedKeySpec pubKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(encKey);
       KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
// I get an exception on the below line
       publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(pubKeySpec);
     } catch (Exception e)
       {
         e.printStackTrace();
       }
}
```

Can someone please help!!

Comment: You made sure there's not a newline at the end of the file, right?  Since you're reading the whole file into the byte array, you need to watch out for that.

Comment: How do I check that? By the way, the exception I'm getting is an InvalidKeySpecException : InvalidKeyException :Invalid Key Format.

Comment: Well, given that you're reading in the whole file contents as your key, a newline would most certainly muck things up.  Since that's safely been eliminated, can you provide a stack trace?  Just knowing that the code fails isn't enough information to be able to diagnose your problem.

Comment: Here is the stack trace:java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: invalid key format at sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory.engineGeneratePublic(Unknown Source) at java.security.KeyFactory.generatePublic(Unknown Source) at Trunk.Main.setPublicKey(Main.java:422) "This is where I set the public key as stated in the code sniplet" at Trunk.Main.Encryption(Main.java:282) at Trunk.Main.main(Main.java:92)

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK X509 encoded keys are binary files encoded using ASN.1. Therefore the question on new-lines at the end does not make any sense.

If you have a text file you have a PEM encoded file and I am currently not sure which KeySpec you have to use in this case.

You may convert the PEM encoded key to a DER encoded key (e.g. using OpenSSL) or you can use [BouncyCastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/) which as support for loading PEM encoded keys.

BTW: Using `keyfis.read(encKey);` is dangerous as the read method only reads up encKey bytes but don't have to. Better create a DataInputStream from the InputStream and use readFully(encKey):

```
new DataInputStream(keyfis).readFully(encKey);
```

Comment: Also, using `available()` to determine the file length is *wrong*. Use [`File.length()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#length()) to determine file lengths.

Comment: I still get the same exceptions but now with IOException: null, here is the stack trace: java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: I
OException: null
        at sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory.engineGeneratePublic(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.KeyFactory.generatePublic(Unknown Source)
        at Trunk.Main.setPublicKey(Main.java:425)
        at Trunk.Main.Encryption(Main.java:282)
        at Trunk.Main.main(Main.java:92)

Comment: As I wrote it looks like you have a PEM encoded key - and you can't load a PEM encoded key using X509EncodedKeySpec

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution but not sure yet if its the right solution coz I still have to get the PrivateKey and decrypt the file but for now I was able to encrypt it using the supplied PublicKey as the modulus but I don’t have the exponent and I just used some common number “65537” as the exponent
Which I read that it is not a critical part of the encryption.

I had to change the logic to use the RSAPublicKeySpec (which uses BigInteger and Base64Decoder)instead of X509EncodedKeySpec to set the KeySpec
And continue to use the KeyFactory object to generate the public key.
Now this logic NEEDS the modulus and exponent.

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[(int) new File(file).length()];
BufferedInputStream f = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
f.read(buffer);
String modulusBase64 = new String(buffer);
BASE64Decoder b64dec = new BASE64Decoder();
String exponentBase64 = "65537";
RSAPublicKeySpec publicKeySpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(new BigInteger    (1,                      b64dec.decodeBuffer(modulusBase64)), new BigInteger(1,     b64dec.decodeBuffer(exponentBase64)));
KeyFactory publicKeyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
publicKey = publicKeyFactory.generatePublic(publicKeySpec);
```

//This is the PublicKey in the file. "J45t4SWGbFzeNuunHliNDZcLVeFU7lOpyNkX1xX+sVNaVJK8Cr0rSjUkDC8h9n+Zg7m0MVYk0byafPycmzWNDynpvj2go9mXwmUpmcQprX1vexxT5j1XmAaBZFYaJRcPWSVU92pdNh1Sd3USdFjgH0LQ5B3s8F95xdyc/5I5LDKhRobx6c1gUs/rnJfJjAgynrE4AsNsNem+STaZWjeb4J+f5Egy9xTSEl6UWxCClgCwhXopy10cBlH8CucpP0cyckOCIOloJ7mEMRCIpp6HPpYexVmXXSikTXh7aQ7tSlTMwUziIERc/zRpyj1Nk96Y7V8AorLFrn1R4Of66mpAdQ=="